# How to normalize validation set in GridSearchCV separately from training set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

How to scale each fold separately in GridSearchCV?

While training an ML model we should normalize (scale) features regarding to the training data. And then use the fitted scaler on the test data. But if using a grid search CV (5 fold) we usually provide it the training data which is already scaled. That then gets separated into folds. But How would we separately scale each of the 4-1 folds?

```py
scl = MinMaxScaler()
scl.fit_transform(X_train)
scl.transform(X_test)

# The training data was scaled all together and
# not train and validation separately
cv = GridSearchCV(MODEL, GRID, scoring='f1', cv=5)
cv.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Please let me know if you have a suggestion how to achieve something like this.

Comment: Why don't you split the training into training and validation sets at first. then scale each set individually

Comment: @ZiyadMoraished the question is clearly about *cross validation*, and not a train/validation split

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what [Pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) are for.

Convert your current model to Pipelined model like this:

```
new_model = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()), ('model', cur_model)])
```

Do not scale your training set beforehand. Every time `fit` is called, Pipeline will automatically fit and transform your training data, (only using training data of course) and call `transform` on test set using fitted `MinMaxScaler`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. You mention not to scale my training set as the pipeline will do it and it makes sense. But I think I still need to fit the scaler with my training set so that I can later transform my test set, is that correct?

Comment: Not if you have `refit=True` in GridSearchCV, which is default. This means GridSearchCV will use entire training set with best found hyperparameter to train a final model, so scaler *within* Pipeline is automatically fitted. In fact, after `cv = GridSearchCV(new_model , GRID, scoring='f1', cv=5).fit(X_train, Y_train)` you can simply call `cv.predict(X_test)` (i.e directly on fitted GridSearchCV) without worrying about scaling or anything else 
`

Comment: This is some ground breaking news :). So let me reiterate if I understand correctly. While the GridSearchCV(pipeline, grid, ...) will be running with my pipeline. And my pipeline will have the preprocessing in place. Then I can use cv.predict(X_test) with not-preprocessed data and sklearn will take care of that? That sounds awesome. Will it work even if I dump the trained pipeline with joblib? and later load it? is the preprocessing from the pipeline still there the dump/load?

Comment: yup, dumping and loading any fitted models or preprocessors is perfectly fine, not just this particular `GridSearchCV(pipeline, grid, ...) ` estimator

Comment: @DominikSajovic For the edification of all, If this strategy worked for you, then 'check' this answer as correct, so that others may be helped.