# How/Where to use StandardScaler with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Standartizing data without pipeline:

```
kfold = KFold(3, shuffle = True, random_state = 3)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = LinearRegression(), param_grid = params, cv = kfold)
 
x = scaler_std.fit_transform(x)
y = scaler_std.fit_transform(np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1))

grid.fit(x,y)
```

Placing scaler inside pipeline:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearRegression())

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = params, cv = kfold)
grid.fit(x,y)
```

These approaches gave me different scores.
Which is more "right" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer to your question : [How to normalize validation set in GridSearchCV separately from training set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58341224/12384070)

The correct way to do it is :

```
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearRegression())
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = params, cv = kfold)
grid.fit(x,y)
```

Because for each fit, it will fit the scaler on the training folds and transform on the test fold, which is the correct way to scale a dataset.

If you do :

```
x = scaler_std.fit_transform(x)
```

Your scaling method will leak informations of the test set during training, which you should avoid.